# What is the first argument in BradleyTerry2 BTm function when data is in two columns?

Tags: r, bradley-terry-model

I have a data frame with two columns. The first column contains the name of an object that won a contest with another object, and the second one contains the name of the loser. I want to fit the Bradley-Terry model using BradleyTerry2 package in R. But I am not sure if I am doing it right. I'll illustrate the question with the flatlizards data attached to this package.

```
info<-as.data.frame(flatlizards[1])

lizModel <- BTm(1, contests.winner, contests.loser, data = info)
```

info data frame is something similar to what I have. It has two columns (contests.winner and contests.loser) and in the first column the objects that won are placed.
The second line of code is the model, and I am not sure what the first argument (called 'outcome' in the function description) should be. I included 1 as I saw on a youtube video, but it also works if I plug 0. In both cases I get two warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred  not sure it is right.

This makes me think that I am doing something wrong. Can someone explain what the 'outcome' argument for my datatable is? The vignette for this package gives examples with other types of datatables. Can this type of datatable be used with this package (I found yes, but again not sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the other type of data frame structure that the BTm function accepts. The results were identical to using the code from my question, so I assume that the code I was asking about is valid.